# OnPageIndexChanging event not triggered for GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I use Stack Overflow all the time for help but I have never had to post my own question on this site.  I am also somewhat new to working with ASP.NET web applications.  I have a GridView that displays records from a datasource and allows paging to view different pages of the grid.  The grid loads fine and displays the data correctly.  The problem I am having is that when clicking on a page number nothing happens and my breakpoints are not triggered for Page_Load or OnPageIndexChanging.  On MSDN, it says that the OnPageIndexChanging event will fire when selecting a page number on the grid but this is not happening.  I have tried all the regularly suggested fixes I have found online for this problem but the issue still persists.  I have posted my code below.  Can anyone tell me what might cause this event to not get triggered?  THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
<asp:GridView ID="_grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" AutoPostBack="true"
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" EnableTheming="False" DataSourceID="vw_SpecFoodBuyerCodeDataSource" Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="_grid_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="_grid_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="_headerCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="_headerCheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="_rowCheckBox" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="SpecId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/SpecPdf.aspx?SpecId={0}"
                        DataTextField="SpecNumber" HeaderText="Spec#" SortExpression="SpecNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Revision" HeaderText="Rev" SortExpression="Revision" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SCNumber" HeaderText="SC#" SortExpression="SCNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SCDescription" HeaderText="SC Description" SortExpression="SCDescription">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorName" HeaderText="Supplier" SortExpression="VendorName" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BuyerCode" HeaderText="Buyer" SortExpression="BuyerCode" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ApprovedDate" HeaderText="Approved" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="ApprovedDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateNeededDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Update Required&lt;br&gt;As Of" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="UpdateNeededDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ApproveUpdateNeededDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Update Sent"
                        SortExpression="ApproveUpdateNeededDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ReceivedUpdateNeededDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Update&lt;br&gt;Received" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="ReceivedUpdateNeededDate" />
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="vw_SpecFoodBuyerCodeDataSource" runat="server" ContextTypeName="PPQAD_QASpecFoodDataLinq.PPQAD_QASpecFoodDataContextManaged" EntityTypeName="" 
    OnSelecting="vw_SpecFoodBuyerCodeDataSource_Selecting" TableName="vw_SpecFoodBuyerCodes">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

And the C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            _buyerCodeListBox.DataSource = WebHelpers.GetCachedBuyerCodes(Page);
            _buyerCodeListBox.DataBind();
            _grid.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(_grid_PageIndexChanging);
            _grid.EnableViewState = true;
            SelectBuyerCodesForCurrentUser();
            _grid.DataBind();
        }
    }
protected void _grid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        _grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        _grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: might be a silly question... but are you sure you're debugging and not just running for attempting to hit your breakpoints?  Additionally, i don't think that AutoPostBack is a valid property for grid views.

Comment: It's not a silly question... Yes I am debugging and I found in another Stack Overflow post that the AutoPostBack needs to be set to true for the paging to work properly.  I have tried it with and without AutoPostBack=true and it has made no change.

Answer (score 0):

It should be more comment then answer, but with my reputation I cannot. So...

The problem can be couse you want to do it not on OnPageIndexChanging but on OnPageIndexChanged.

The problem could be also becouse you have attached the _grid_PageIndexChanging to the event of gridview controller twice: first time in controller definistion in .aspx file and second time in the Page_Load. But honestly - it should work anyway (fired two times should not hurt). But I think it is couse you attached it second time after doing bug research.

Also I would sugest to do all you do in Page_Load rather in Page_Init.
This event handler is prior to Page_Load and can fix the problem as on Page_Load the gridview could be already rendered or initited?

Comment: Thanks for your input Jerry.  You are correct in assuming why I attached the event handler twice but it shouldn't make any difference, like you stated.  I also tried using the OnPageIndexChanged event rather than OnPageIndexChanging and I have the same problem.  The OnPageIndexChanged event does not trigger either.  I will try putting the code into the Page_Init and see if it makes any difference.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the Page_Load code into the Page_Init did not make any difference.  The problem still persists...

Comment: Well this is some really ugly bug/issue. I would suggest then to gather all info about web server and .NET runtime - maybe something is out of date or notcompatibile? I am using mainly xsp server and it doesnt support few things. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SqlDataReader? If yes, then change to DataSet. I also encoutered that kind of problem but when i changed to DataSet it worked. also copy paste your Datasource after the `_grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;`

Comment: I am not currently using SqlDataReader but I did try it using SqlDataReader and a DataSet before I posted this question.  This unfortunately did not solve my problem of the event not firing.

Comment: Set PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric". You don't have PagerSettings-Mode in your GridVIew.

Comment: Thanks Kio.  I put PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" in the GridView tag but still no change.  No events are trigger when clicking on the paging numbers.